# failed ubuntu installation

Tags: wubi

so i downloaded ubuntu 12.04 and i unzipped the folder. I didn't burn it on a DVD I just launched it of the download folder. I clicked on the wubi.exe icon and proceeded to fill out the items and when i clicked next the time remaining said it was 3 Hours so i canceled it. After i burnt it on a DVD and launched the wubi.exe icon it just prompt me with Demo and Full Installation and Learn More. so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to install Ubuntu using Wubi,you do not need to burn anything.

Wubi will install Ubuntu inside your windows system.Installing Ubuntu from an .iso file which you burnt in a usb or a CD will install Ubuntu at another partition.

My guess is that at the download page of Ubuntu you clicked the "Download" button at the bottom instead of the "Start Download" button at the top right.

You can download Wubi (which comes in the form of a windows executable file .exe) [at this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&release=&bits=).

From [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32) link you can download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in an .iso file which you have to burn.

Do not know how to burn an .iso in windows?Microsoft already has a [tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-from-an-ISO-file) for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer a downloading a wubi.exe & Ubuntu-i386.tar.xz from this [link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) and from windows just open command prompt and run  wubi.exe as,

```
wubi.exe --dimagepath=path\to\ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz
```

It will take very less time than installing from Ubuntu iso and wubi....